# Need to find the size of every image (greater than 100KB )which stored in binary form in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have tried the following query but it was failing

```
db.getCollection('images').aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
      "practiceId": "$practiceId",
      "imageSize": { $binarySize: "$data" }
    }
    }])
```

[image: Error which I am getting]

And my sample data in mongodb is like

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60be3c9ea77d6312514276384"),
    "_class" : "com.test.images.model.ImageEntity",
    "practiceId" : NumberLong(242),
    "fileName" : "img.jpg",
    "contentType" : "image/jpeg",
    "data" : { "$binary" : "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", "$type" : "00" },
    "thumbnail" : false
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a problem with the data format. This one works:

```
db.images.insertOne({
   "_class": "com.test.images.model.ImageEntity",
   "practiceId": NumberLong(242),
   "fileName": "img.jpg",
   "contentType": "image/jpeg",
   "thumbnail": false,
   data: BinData(0, "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")
})

db.images.aggregate([
   {
      $project: {
         "practiceId": "$practiceId",
         "imageSize": { $binarySize: "$data" }
      }
   }
])

{ 
    "practiceId" : 242, 
    "imageSize" : 4207.0
}
```

I insert these two documents:

```
db.images.insertMany([
   {
      author: "you",
      data: {
         "$binary": "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",
         "$type": "00"
      },
   },
   {
      author: "me",
      data: BinData(0, "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")
   }
])
```

The mongoexport looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": { "$oid": "60f92b42607c82337782654e" },
    "author": "you",
    "data": {
        "$binary": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAk...",
        "$type": "00"
    }
},
{
    "_id": { "$oid": "60f92b42607c82337782654f" },
    "author": "me",
    "data": {
        "$binary": {
            "base64": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAA...",
            "subType": "00"
        }
    }
}
```

Looks like mongo does not recognize it as Binary Data, the output is different.

Comment: I guess my mongo version is old 3.2.5, so $binarySize is not supporting

Comment: With new version it is giving me proper output but the image size in output is in bytes.
Is there any way we can get it in KB

Comment: Oh yes, I did not pay attention to your error message. It's a number so simply `imageSize: { $divide: [{ $binarySize: "$data" }, 1024] }`

Comment: Thanks for your help! 
but is there any way we can get the image size for older version of mongo?

Comment: I don't think so, you need a more recent version.

Comment: Can anyone help with this?